# who create class file JVM or compiler in java?

Tags: java

The compilation and execution of a Java program is a two-step process. During the compilation phase the Java compiler compiles the source code and generates bytecode. My question is who is responsible for .class file?`

Comment: Byte code is written to .clsss file.

Comment: I'm not responsible for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A Java class file (containing bytecode) is produced by a Java compiler from Java programming language source files (.java files) containing Java classes. If a source file has more than one class, each class is compiled into a separate class file.

Source : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file

Answer (score 1):

The class file contains the bytecode - it's created by the compiler, and executed by the JVM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file